# Nodejs Passport Authentication

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

As per my understanding, Node.js "passport" module in its local strategy is comparing the user from the database. We can also do this by just doing a single database query to compare user. Is there any other functionality that passport is providing except other strategy like Facebook, Google etc ?

What is the difference between using passport for local strategy and simply doing a database query?

Comment: @Rjinal - **PassportJS** adds methods to `req` object like `req.logout()` or proporties like `req.user`. Simple query to DB doesn`t do this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you more specific?  What is the requirement that you have and trying answer with passprt.js strategy?  If you are looking to understand on how to implement passprt.js you can [read it as a complete example at here.](http://eshwartechtalks.blogspot.in/2015/07/nodejs-rest-api-authentication-using.htmlhttp://eshwartechtalks.blogspot.in/2015/07/nodejs-rest-api-authentication-using.html?m=1)

Comment: Not really an answer, more a comment :-)

Comment: I know how to use but question is why to use, where is the difference between using passport for local strategy and simply doing a database query